# Is there a way to extrude an edge ring diagonally?

Tags: modeling, edges, extrude

is there a way to extrude an edge ring diagonally?

This is my model, I need to extrude the edge ring keeping it's direction:

[image]

This must be simple enough, yet I couldn't find an answer for now, maybe I'm expressing myself badly in the search or something.

Comment: i am not sure how you created your model, but if you have a rotated cylinder you could just select it like you did and press 'E'. But looks like this does not work for you. Would you mind providing your blend file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your *Transform Orientation* to *Normal*.

[image]

Remember to change it back to *Global* for all of your regular stuff. :)

https://docs.blender.org/manual/es/2.79/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/orientations.html

Comment: I did tried to use the normal orientation before, it happens I was trying to extrude without a fixed axis. Extrude along Y axis kinda worked I guess, though a little bent.

Comment: There should be a way to get it exact.  Perhaps someone will come along with a better answer for you.